# Powershell | DownloadString | External website | Return

Tags: powershell

I'm a totally powershell newbie, so please be indulgent ;)

I'm trying to write a script where a machine check an external website waiting for a the word: "test" to execute a download. The things goes like this:

```
$Word = 'test'
$WebClientObject = New-Object Net.WebClient
$comment = "http://MySite.wordpress.com/comment_section/"
$WebClientObject.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36)")
While($True){
$CommentResult = $WebClientObject.DownloadString($comment)
$Found = $CommentResult.contains($Word)
If($Found) {
IEX $WebClientObject.DownloadString('http://A_Server_That_Is_Accessible/Tasks_to_do')
Task_to_do and some blabla commands
Return
}
Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
}
```

*I'm running powershell 2.0. Windows7*

**What happened:**

- the download is not executed over internet
- it is not a issue coming from IPs or paths

**What i've done next:**

- I directly write the different commands in the powershell prompt:

**-->** the While($True) initiate an endless loop without exiting it.

To make the trick i need to "double click return on my keyboard", the loop's ending and the "downloadstring" command is finally executed.

Still remember i'm more than a newbie, right? :(

- i tried *"break"* *"return"* or *"exit"* bu impossible to quit the
  loop.
- I tried to put many double carriage return in my script also without
  any success.

Would someone please indicates me the way to do this simple thing...? :)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: First off, I'd recommend upgrading to a newer version of PowerShell.  [PowerShell 4 is available for Windows 7](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40855) now, and at the very least, [you should be on PowerShell 3](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595), for the extra functionality it provides.  Second, yeah, [`break`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847873.aspx) is what should do what you want.  Can you include the code that contains the `break` and doesn't work?

Comment: **break** does not seems to be the solution..and my aim is that people of my organization use this script, and i just do not have the possibility to update all the machines to a newer version of Powershell..

Answer (score 2):

There is at least three issues with your script:

1. `contains` doesn't work the way you think it does. It tells whether a collection of reference values includes a single test value. In layman's terms, it operates only on elements of arrays and looks for exact match. But what you get in your `$CommentResult` is one long string containing all page's HTML code. So `contains` treats is as an array with one element and because this element is not an exact match of string 'test', it returns `False`.
2. In your `if` block, you don't have to use `Invoke-Expression` cmdlet (`IEX` is an alias for it) to call `DownloadString` method of `$WebClientObject`.
3. You really need to do some HTML parsing (Html Agility Pack [will do](http://powershell.org/wp/forums/topic/find-text-on-a-web-page/#post-17913)), or at least a regex to match a word (and it's better to be a *very* unique word). Because string `test` itself can occur in HTML as part of a tag, e.g.:

   ```
   <img src='http://server.com/protestant.jpg' />
   ```

I've fixed your script to use a regex and match anything, that happens to contain the string `test` (this includes *pro**test***, *de**test***, *la**test***, ***test***ament and so on) in a HTML code of web-page. Try it and modify to your needs afterwards:

```powershell
$Word = 'test'
$comment = 'http://MySite.wordpress.com/comment_section/'

$WebClientObject = New-Object -TypeName Net.WebClient
$WebClientObject.Headers.Add('User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36)')

While($true)
{
    if($WebClientObject.DownloadString($comment) -match $Word)
    {
        $Html = $WebClientObject.DownloadString('http://A_Server_That_Is_Accessible/Tasks_to_do')
        #Task_to_do and some blabla commands
        break
    }

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
}
```